# Acceptance tests for REST API - Shoud I deal with all cases?

Tags: rest, testing, acceptance-testing

Our team is doing ATDD(Acceptance Test Driven Development) for our projects.

And I have a question.

I write API tests like below.

1) creating fixtures

2) sending headers, query, path, body to endpoint.

3) assert response of status code, body, etc

**And here is the question!**

Should I write all test cases for exceptional case (like invalid body field and value combinations) in acceptance tests?

For example, `POST /users` receives body like `{ name: "steve", age: 27, account: "test", password: "test1234" }`

Do you write test cases for all body input combinations? (If `name` is empty, return 400 / If `name` is too short, return 400 / If `age` is not number, return 400 / If password does not contain number, return 400 and so on)

There are too many cases:(

If you don't, can you share with me how you deal with this?

Answer (score 1):

You do need to cover those cases, but you don't want to cover them all at high levels. In order to write fast and maintainable tests you need to follow [test pyramid](http://qala.io/blog/test-pyramid.html) writing a lot of low-level (unit) tests and few high-level (system) tests.

So what you want to do is check all the validation rules in unit tests (for each field) and then create only 1 high-level negative test per endpoint to check that validation is *invoked* and the error format is correct.